# Using cURL or wget for multiple sites

Tags: curl, wget

Is there a simple way to download an image file from multiple (sequentially numbered) sites,  and change the filename to match the download location?

For example,

www.001.mysite.com/photo.jpg

www.002.mysite.com/photo.jpg

...

...

www.050.mysite.com/photo.jpg

The photo is named the same on each site.  Is it possible to download those photos, rename them like photo001.jpg (corresponding to the site it came from), And put them into a directory with the current date?

I started with some searches...found ideas that help with a portion of this and others with different portions but when I attempt to make it work, I either get nothing or errors.

Comment: Do you use a programming or scripting language?

Comment: A quick command line, assuming you are on macOS or Linux and bash is the shell of your choice: `for i in {1..50}; do j=$(printf %03d $i); echo curl -o image$j.jpg http://www.$j.mysite.com/photo.jpg; done`. Tweak it until it looks like you need then remove `echo` to let it do it (that `echo` makes it just display the commands instead of running them).

Comment: you can use a config file for that. That's -K from the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bash for this, but I don't know Bash, so here's a Python example that makes use of multiple concurrent processes to reduce waiting on webservers, in case you need to download a lot of images:

```
import os
num_images = 100 # change me
num_concurrent = 4 # to be tweaked
i = 0
while i < num_images:
    calls = []
    for i2 in range(num_concurrent):
        # this will download 0, 1, ..., 9, 10, 11
        # change the number format if necessary
        call = "curl www.{0}.mysite.com/photo.jpg > {0}.jpg".format(i)
        calls.append(call)
        i += 1
    os.system(" & ".join(calls))
```

This will run batches of `num_concurrent` image downloads. I advise you to be conservative when tweaking this because very high numbers of concurrent connections will wreak havoc with TCP congestion control and may also get you blocked from the target website.